# How do we access popup in android appium

Tags: android, appium

I'm unable to find in app popups in uiautomator, is there a way to find out xpath for pop-ups in android?

I have tried using uiautomaotor for different versions of android os (4.4 to 7)

Answer (score 0):

popup are not part of your layout and hence you cant see it in your view hierarchy. so can't use Xpath.